# Remove record by id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Why I can't remove record by _id?

Code:

```
db.collection('posts', function(err, collection) {
   collection.remove({_id: '4d512b45cc9374271b00000f'});
});
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to pass the `_id` value as an ObjectID, not a string:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

db.collection('posts', function(err, collection) {
   collection.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID('4d512b45cc9374271b00000f')});
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove array of ids at once?

Comment: @Denis Sure, just use [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in):  `{_id: {$in: idsArray}}`

Comment: Couldn't find this answer in the documentation, very helpful

Comment: latest mongodb for nodejs, it's `ObjectId`, not `ObjectID`

Answer (score 6):

MongoDb has now marked the remove method as deprecated.  It has been replaced by two separate methods: deleteOne and deleteMany.

Here is their relevant getting started guide: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/remove/

and here is a quick sample:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

db.collection('posts', function(err, collection) {
   collection.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID('4d512b45cc9374271b00000f')}, function(err, results) {
       if (err){
         console.log("failed");
         throw err;
       }
       console.log("success");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

With TypeScript, you can to it using imports, instead of requiring the whole library

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb'   

 

db.collection('posts', function(err, collection) {
   collection.deleteOne({_id: new ObjectID('4d512b45cc9374271b00000f')});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First include mongodb

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
```

You have to include the ObjectID from mongodb

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Then Use

```
var delete_id = request.params.id;//your id

 collection.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(delete_id.toString())});
```

1000% works...

Answer (score 0):

i think we have to require mongodb as const
and use it with mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled with this problem today and I find that the fix is:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
databaseName.collectionName.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(id)} , (err)=>{
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('Deleted'+id);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.