# MongoDB Delete ObjectId Not Working With Format

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, rest

I'm trying to delete something but the current format below doesn't work.

It works when I input it manually and write `"_id":ObjectId("Idhere")`. It doesn't even work when I use `JSON.stringify`. It also works in postman.

Does someone see what I'm missing?

```js
 router.delete('/wishlist', (req, res) => {
    const db = mongoUtil.getDb();
   
    db.db("mern-auth-2").collection("savedbooks").deleteOne({
         _id:ObjectId(req.body._id),
    }) 
 });
```

Comment: Since you are using Mongo with `express`, I suggest using the [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) driver instead of the native MongoDB Node.js drive

Comment: You need to create an instance of the `ObjectId`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12901901/10893256) answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

change the code from :

```
db.db("mern-auth-2").collection("savedbooks").deleteOne({
     _id:ObjectId(req.body._id),
})
```

to :

```
db.db("mern-auth-2").collection("savedbooks").deleteOne({
     _id: req.body._id,
})
```

hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
    db.db("mern-auth-2").collection("savedbooks").deleteOne({
         _id:req.body._id
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it doesn't work